# Postgresql integration with Google sheets

Tags: postgresql, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet which needs to be updated weekly with the data queried from postgresql.

This what I have done: I have established connection with both postgresql and google spread sheet with R, and updated the google spread sheet with new information after pulling the data from both google spread sheet and postgresql. However, the structure of the spread sheet changed after updating.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this.